# Cant able to receive response from Web service using curl from C++

Tags: c++, web-services, curl, soap

I am trying to get response from web service using curl and c++. I have tried calling the web service from terminal. It works fine I can receive the response.

But I cannot able to reproduce the same through c++.

```
 Request.xml
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:blz="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/“>
 <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
   <blz:getBank>
      <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz>
    </blz:getBank>
  </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>


void dataFromWebService :: connectWithWebservice(){    

struct curl_slist *header = NULL;
header = curl_slist_append (header, "Content-Type:text/xml");
header = curl_slist_append (header, "charset=UTF-8");
header = curl_slist_append (header, "SOAPAction:urn:getBank");

curl = curl_easy_init();    

if(curl == NULL){

    cout<<"CURL is NULL";
}

const char *myUrl = "http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService";

//const char *myUrl = "http://11.22.33.231:9080/VehicleInfoQueryService.asm";
if(curl){

    string Mydata;

    char errbuf[CURL_ERROR_SIZE];
    struct MemoryStruct chunk;

    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);  /* will be grown as needed by the realloc above */
    chunk.size = 0;    /* no data at this point */


    FILE * rfp = fopen("request.xml", "r");

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, myUrl);

    //curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_READDATA, rfp);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, header);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

     char *response = NULL;
    /* passing the pointer to the response as the callback parameter */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void *)&chunk);



    errbuf[0] = 0;
    cout<< "The result from webservice "<<endl;

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */

    curlCode = curl_easy_perform(curl);

    /* send all data to this function  */

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);

    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_WRITEDATA,(void *)&chunk);


    cout <<"curl code-- "<<curlCode<<endl;


    //  always cleanup
    if(curlCode != CURLE_OK  | curlCode != 0) {
        size_t len = strlen(errbuf);
        fprintf(stderr, "\nlibcurl: (%d) ", curlCode);
        if(len)
            fprintf(stderr, "%s%s", errbuf,
                    ((errbuf[len - 1] != '\n') ? "\n" : ""));
        else
            fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", curl_easy_strerror(curlCode));
    } else {
        /*
         * Now, our chunk.memory points to a memory block that is chunk.size
         * bytes big and contains the remote file.
         */

        printf("%lu bytes retrieved\n", (long)chunk.size);

        cout<<"My Chunck -- "<<chunk.memory<<endl;
    }
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

}

}
```

output from code:

```
The result from webservice 
*   Trying 80.152.243.114...
* Connected to www.thomas-bayer.com (80.152.243.114) port 80 (#0)
> GET /axis2/services/BLZService HTTP/1.1
Host: www.thomas-bayer.com
Accept: */*
Content-Type:text/xml
SOAPAction:urn:getBank

< HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: application/xml;charset=UTF-8
< Date: Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:56:36 GMT
< Connection: close
< Content-Length: 2388
< 
* Closing connection 0
curl code-- 0
2388 bytes retrieved
My Chunck -- <?xml version="1.0" ?><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The endpoint reference (EPR) for the Operation not found is /axis2/services/BLZService and the WSA Action = null
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.DispatchPhase.checkPostConditions(DispatchPhase.java:86)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.Phase.invoke(Phase.java:308)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.invoke(AxisEngine.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:132)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:125)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:119)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:799)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:242)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:620)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
</Exception>
Hello, World!
```

From terminal:

command:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:getBank" --data @request.xml http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService
```

Output:

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8’?>
 <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/“>
  <soapenv:Body>  
     <ns1:getBankResponse xmlns:ns1="http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/“>
        <ns1:details>
              <ns1:bezeichnung>
                   Deutsche Bank Filiale
              </ns1:bezeichnung>
       <ns1:bic>
               DEUTDEFFXXX
       </ns1:bic>
       <ns1:ort>
               Frankfurt am Main
       </ns1:ort> 
       <ns1:plz>
               60254
       </ns1:plz>
      </ns1:details>
    </ns1:getBankResponse>
   </soapenv:Body>
 </soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: There is a typo right at the beginning of the request.xml `soapenv:Envelop`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this type happened while I copied my xml to SO.

Comment: There is no check whether `rfp` is valid, could it be that `fopen` fails?

Comment: Try changing `myUrl` to `http://www.thomas-bayer.com/axis2/services/BLZService?wsdl`

Comment: old_mountain This returns only wsdl file from the web service.

Comment: Steeve, the file is open.

Comment: If I change "Content-Type:text/xml” to "Content-Type: application/soap+xml”, I get `?xml version="1.0" ?><Exception>org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Stream closed
 at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:417) ….`  as a response. Any guess what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is little embarrassing to answer my own question.

I have to use Http Post with the request char* instead of file pointer of the request.

So the following works.

```
 char* req= "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:blz=\"http://thomas-bayer.com/blz/\">  <soapenv:Header/> <soapenv:Body>   <blz:getBank>  <blz:blz>50070010</blz:blz> </blz:getBank>  </soapenv:Body>  </soapenv:Envelope>";

 curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_HTTPPOST, 1L);   
 curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, req);
```

This may be the reason [SOAP only works with POST method even though it is transported by HTTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4646146/http-soap-get-post)  since "Standard SOAP services are using only HTTP POST because they require complex SOAP request (XML) which cannot be included in query string.”

but I don’t know how [this example from curl](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/CURLOPT_HTTPGET.html) works.

Thanks.